# How to change nbconvert webpdf page size?

Tags: nbconvert

I am calling nbconvert using the Python API, and using `WebPDFExporter` to generate a PDF from a notebook. However, tables in the output are sometimes too wide for the default page.

I've followed [docs about customizing templates](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) and was able to get an error if my custom template is not in a template path directory, but I couldn't get any change in the output PDF.

Here's my rendering code:

```py
    notebook_node = nbformat.read(notebook_output_path, as_version=4)
    # Use WebPDFExporter instead of just PDFExporter so that HTML style attributes such
    # as table cell colors are respected. This requires a number of system packages
    # to be installed, specified in the Dockerfile.
    conf = Config()
    # This uses Chrome internally to render the PDF + styling, so allow downloading
    # it. Setting disable-chromium-sandbox is required in a Docker container:
    # https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1490 .
    conf.WebPDFExporter.allow_chromium_download = True
    conf.WebPDFExporter.disable_sandbox = True
    conf.WebPDFExporter.paginate = False  # Doesn't seem to work.
    # Only show printed strings and charts/tables.
    conf.TemplateExporter.exclude_input = True
    conf.TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt = True
    conf.TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt = True
    # Use a customized layout from a local template file.
    conf.TemplateExporter.extra_template_basedirs = str(_TEMPLATES_DIR)
    conf.TemplateExporter.template_name = "widepdf"
    pdf_exporter = WebPDFExporter(config=conf)
    pdf_data, unused_resources = pdf_exporter.from_notebook_node(notebook_node)
    with open(pdf_path, "wb") as pdf_file:
        pdf_file.write(pdf_data)
```

Here's the template I attempted, where `widepdf/` is a subdirectory of `_TEMPLATES_DIR` above.

I think my `widepdf/conf.json` is roughly what it should be:

```json
{
  "base_template": "webpdf",
  "mimetypes": {
    "application/pdf": true
  }
}
```

My `widepdf/index.pdf.j2` is just trying to see any change to the output:

```
{%- extends 'webpdf/index.pdf.j2' -%}

{% block body %}
<p>Extra body</p>
{{ super() }}
{% endblock body %}

{% block extra_css %}
{{ super() }}
<p>Hello extra template content.</p>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: red !important;
}
p {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
@page {
    size: 14in 60in !important;
}
</style>
{% endblock extra_css %}
```

If I remove the `widepdf` directory then I get an error that the template `widepdf` could not be found, so I do think `nbconvert` is attempting to use it. But I'm not sure why the `@page` size is not being changed (nor any of my other debugging style changes showing up).